# Content Wrapper Problmes with CSS styling

Tags: css

I have gotten frustrated enough trying to finish this mock up website that I have come crawling to you guys for help. I am having 2 issues at the moment. First my content wrapper background which is all white keeps getting pushed up whenever I open Firebug to examine my code. Second my content wrapper white background is not including my footer in Firefox. In IE it includes it most of the way but not 100%. Cuts off a line of text. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
    html,body {height:100%;width:100%;} 

    html,body,#End {margin:0;padding:0;} 

    body {
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    }

    Content_Wrap {
    text-align: left;
    width: 864px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    } 

    address{
font-family:'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
float:left;
color:#195a80;
height:100px;
width:auto;
}

    copyright{
font-family:'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
float:right;
color:#195a80;
height:40px;
width:auto;
}

    footer{
height:300px;
width:inherit;
float:left;
}
```

Address and copyright sit inside the footer while everything except for my end div sits inside the content wrap. When I check with Firebug it shows the footer within the wrapper.

Link to mockup I am working on. http://ninjasquared.com/LWM/

Comment: Can we see relevant html? Put it all in a fiddle too so we can see what you mean

Comment: Why are you specifying body position as absolute ?

Comment: http://ninjasquared.com/LWM/ here is the actual mock up I am working on. Couple things to disreguard the floating map and button. Yes I am aware they are in the middle of the screen; but, I have been messing with my code to try and get my wrapper to work correctly. Also the footers height is not suppose to be 300px. It is suppose to be flush with the end div.

Comment: In response to body position to being absolute I was trying to keep the wrapper from moving around on me. I know the wrapper is a separate div; however, I have gotten desperate and gave that a shot. I forgot to remove it as it did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `height:100%` from `#Content_Wrap` and let wrapper to fill around it. Adding `overflow: hidden;` to `#Content_Wrap` will do trick for you!

Just replace your `#Content_Wrap` with this:

**CSS:**

```
#Content_Wrap {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: left;
width: 864px;
}
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to trying to help. This didn't help though as I should of posted the full code.

Comment: OK thanks, now clear what you want? You want the `footer` within `#End` div or anything else? Because as per your question it's not clear.

Comment: Trying to figure out why the wrapper background (which is white) is shifting up and down while I open up Firebug to inspect the code. Also having issues with the wrapper background not wrapping around the footer 100%. I am still trying to get used to stackoverflow. Still a newbie. I would post out the entire code but it seems easier to just link to my html mockup. http://ninjasquared.com/LWM/. I am trying to get the html bugs out so I can start converting it to a WordPress template.

Comment: I have updated my answer, try it and let me know if you have still problem with it and further help.

Comment: It worked perfect!! Thank you very much!! Greatly appreciate you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting IDs, classes?
`body` and `html` are elements
but `Content_Wrap`  and `copyright` are probably IDs or classes and should be referenced like `#copyright` or `.copyright` respectively. 
Here's a [w3schools link for ID/class references](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp).

Comment: Yes I am using divs. I do use # I just removed them when I posted this.

Comment: The body and html elements are what I am using to center the page correctly. Threw them out there because I am not sure if they can be screwing up the wrapper somehow.